# How can I stop my neighbor from seeing my web surfing?

Tags: privacy, snooping

My relationship with one of my neighbors went downhill after I discovered his son trespassing on my property.  I complained to his dad.  Instead of giving me an apology for their son's behavior, his mom went berserk, calling me names (actually, screaming at me) and making it clear that they have some hardware or software which can see the web pages I go to.  At home I use Time Warner Home Wifi, which requires a password.  Apparently this is no barrier to them. (Previously I had used Verizon Mifi, and I still use that when I travel or when the Time Warner is not working, which is rare.)

Questions:

1. Is their behavior likely a violation of the federal [Electronic Communications Privacy Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Communications_Privacy_Act)? If probably yes, I can complain to the police. What, if anything, can the police do? Even if the police take my neighbors' software, it could be easily re-purchased.
2. If I have something really private, I suppose I can drive a distance away and use the Verizon Mifi.  How much distance would be safe?  One mile? Five miles?  More?
3. Is there anything else I can do?  I am not accessing illegal websites but I don't want my neighbor looking over my shoulder on health, financial, or other personal issues; if that makes sense.
4. Can I get this software myself and "see if they are watching me"?

Comment: A password does not protect anything.  What protects a wireless connection is the encryption of the payload of the 802.11 packets, the encryption is performed according to an IEEE defined protocol.  Whatever router you have you must be capable of using a protocol that implements encryption: WEP, WPA, or WPA2.

Comment: chances that your random neighbors with abusing mother actually have the capability to break into your wifi and read all your traffic is pretty slim. Do you have any reason to believe they can, besides them telling you so?

Comment: It's hard to decide to delve into this topic when we're going on some random  3rd person's claim that they can see your traffic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, most likely. But hard to prove. You would need hard evidence. You would also need to prove that you had taken sufficient precautions. Even then, you'd need a police department with an electronic crime division and with the time and willingness to get involved with a neighbour dispute - unlikely.
2. The MiFi is good and likely harder to break into even locally. For greater security, even a block or two away should be fine.
3. Yes, lots.

   - First make sure your Wi-Fi is actually secure.
   - Lock down the router so that it only accepts connections from known MAC addresses.
   - Make sure you are using WPA2 and have turned off WPS.
   - Change the SSID and if the router supports it, turn off the SSID broadcast (makes is slightly harder to find).
   - Change the WPA2 passcode to something long and truly random.
   - Make sure that any legitimate devices on your network are secure too. Don't ignore this step.
   - Use wired connections instead of WiFi.
   - Turn down the broadcast strength on the Wi-Fi to make it harder to pick up remotely.
   - Finally, you could buy into a VPN service which strongly encrypts the traffic from the router (or maybe even from the PC) to the VPN host making it impossible to eavesdrop.
4. No, it is virtually impossible without significant surveillance kit to monitor the monitors.

There is a very tiny possibility that they have tapped into your local broadband connection or even bugged your building - but that is getting rather paranoid. In that case, except for using a VPN, they might still be able to see unencrypted traffic. But encrypted traffic such as HTTPS couldn't be viewed without malware on the PC. Also make sure that your email traffic is encrypted, check with your provider and check the settings on any computer that accesses email via a client.

You might also want to think about video surveillance around and inside your property - neighbour disputes can turn really nasty. Certainly consider alarms on your main building and any outbuildings with valuables.

Overall, get professional advice. Don't go it alone. Share your concerns quietly - at least at first. You want other people to know there is a potential issue in case things escalate. Do what you can to defuse the situation and above all, make sure *you* stay on the right side of the law.

BTW, not sure about the US but in the UK it is only trespass if someone damages something.

---

UPDATE: Another thought. Your router will have a page listing the MAC & IP addresses for connected devices so you will want to monitor that for unexpected entries.

Comment: I'd avoid the SSID broadcast hiding and the known MAC address filtering. IMO those have more downsides than upsides and won't help at all against somebody sniffing your WiFi.

Comment: I don't normally recommend them either but in this case, it seems a sensible precaution. SSID hiding makes it harder for the OP to connect but also much harder for a casual attacker, it forces a much higher level of knowledge. Similarly for MAC pinning though that is much easier on the OP since you just connect the devices you want and then note the MAC addresses. I've also added another thought to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that the network you're on is not safe.  Basic good IT security hygiene would be:

- Ensure that you're only accessing sensitive documents over a TLS (such as HTTPS) connection.  Unless you live next to some high end secret crypto bunker, that should solve most of it.
- Make sure your PC's don't have any backdoor installed on them, which would give them access to see your screen.
- Change your account / wifi passwords regularly; and make them hard to guess.  No pets names, number plates, anything that is guessable.
- I am not a lawyer, but watching your neighbors communication without consent is illegal in many countries.  You can get legal aid here, but you should go on more than a "they told me that ...".

They may be bluffing, because shouting that you're hacking your neighbors network (yours in this case) is not the wisest thing to do.

Nevertheless, ensure you have good IT security practices.  Difficult to guess passwords, antivirus / anti malware with updated signatures, use encrypted channels (http, ...) and enable things like 2FA where possible.

Comment: I agree that bluffing is more likely than really being able to do what is described. Interesting question anyway though.

Comment: Especially when combined with other good computer hygiene, changing online account passwords is often useless at best, and downright counterproductive at worst. https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/passwords#dont-change

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - that is assuming that breaches are made public.  If your account is compromised but not publicized yet, I think it increases security.

Comment: @m1ke That assumes the attacker got your password in the first place. As I specifically discuss under that bullet point, the rest of the page is pretty much meant to ensure that the attacker is unable to get your password in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I realize all of this was written in 2016. So, I would like to give you a 2018 reply. All of the things written to you are of some use.  Still in 2018 there is more to be concerned about.

On your computer, keep changing your password.

Some tips to keep jerks out:

- Get a really good firewall like Norton.
- Hardwire your computer. Get rid of wifi or wireless connections.

Keep in mind, that if a person does this kind of thing, especially today, make sure you never place your phone next to your computer when typing in a password. There are spy apps that can capture your computer passwords just by being near your computer. And before you say, how is that possible? All a crook has to do is send an encoded message to your phone if they know your number and viola, they are on board for everything.  Your calls, your texts and so much more. That is currently what I am dealing with.

Be aware...be mindful...and watch over your shoulder...people are very different today.

Comment: I removed your personal story because it does not apply as an answer.

Comment: Changing your password is not so useful. 2FA is far more useful. Norton is more of an anti-virus package. Why get rid of wifi? People are no different today as in 2016.